# angular-translate translation object with some equal translations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using `angular-translate` to make a web application multilanguage. Everything works fine, and by now I have structured my translations so that I have:

```
$translateProvider.translations("en", {
    "LANGUAGE": {
        "ENGLISH": "english",
        "GERMAN": "german",
        "ITALIAN": "italian",
        "FRENCH": "french",
    }
});
```

Let's say I want to add `BUTTONS.ENGLISH` with the same definition of `LANGUAGE.ENGLISH`. Is it possible to reference it in some way like `BUTTONS.ENGLISH = this.LANGUAGE.ENGLISH`?

```
$translateProvider.translations("en", {
    "LANGUAGE": {
        "ENGLISH": "english",
        "GERMAN": "german",
        "ITALIAN": "italian",
        "FRENCH": "french",
    },
    "BUTTONS": {
        "ENGLISH": this["LANGUAGE"]["ENGLISH"] // ???
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to do is not possible because of javascript scope issues but you can always use interpolation inside a translation to call another translation like the following example.

```
 "ENGLISH": "{{ 'LANGUAGE.ENGLISH' | translate }}"
```

This way you can guarantee that your key will correspond to another key value which maybe can make it easier to maintain.

Full code:

```
$translateProvider.translations("en", {
    "LANGUAGE": {
        "ENGLISH": "english",
        "GERMAN": "german",
        "ITALIAN": "italian",
        "FRENCH": "french",
    },
    "BUTTONS": {
        "ENGLISH": "{{ 'LANGUAGE.ENGLISH' | translate }}"
    }
});
```

> **FURTHER NOTE ABOUT PERFORMANCE ISSUES**: I think it won't cause any huge performance issues despite that it's more expensive than a plain string, but it would be the same cost that using variable replacement, but yet, more expensive than a plain string (I've tested and normally is 25% less expensive than interpolated strings), so avoid using it in large scale.

Comment: It does work and seems to be the only viable way, so thank you for the answer. Do you think is this efficient?

Comment: @Naigel I think it won't cause any huge performance issues despite that it's more expensive than a plain string, but it would be the same cost that using variable replacement, but yet, more expensive than a plain string (I've tested and normally is 25% less expensive than interpolated string), so avoid using it in large scale.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer and explanation. Maybe you can include this information in the answer as future reference?

Comment: @Naigel You're right, I've update my answer with that note.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can't access object literal other properties with `this` (`this` has the same value during the initialization of the literal that it did before-hand).

Comment: In this case, `this`, will always be the `window` object, won't it?

Comment: So is there no way to access easily the current object somehow, right?

Comment: With Angular, you can see LenilsonDeCastro's answer. With Javascript alone, you'd probably have to split the object in two distinct objects...